# What goods did Germany trade during World War II, and with whom?

Tags: world-war-two, nazi-germany, economy, trade

I have scoured the internet for numerical figures and an actual list of raw materials to no avail. Moreover, I am reasonably certain that many of you are very knowledgeable upon this subject matter, and are more than able to inform me. I would greatly appreciate this.

In addition, it would be very nice if anyone could recommend any archive/database or book that may help me in my research.

Thanks once again.

Comment: I found an extensive bibliography on the topic: https://www.archives.gov/research/holocaust/bibliographies/trade-with-third-reich.html  - there were neutral countries, such as Spain, Sweden, and Switzerland, which would trade with Germany - and the German economy between 1939-1945 was supported by the spoils of conquest, confiscated assets from the holocaust, and outrageous currency exchange rates within the occupied territories (so-called 'occupation marks')

Comment: Note as well that Germany derived a lot of its resources from a snatch-and-grab operation: by invading the USSR in 1941, they sought to make themselves largely independent of trade by grabbing mineral-rich deposits, plantations, factories and other assets. The failure of this operation led to their increased dependence upon trade and, as such, the impoverishment of their own population. Cesarani (*The Final Solution*) has some information on this, but he doesn't go into detail as regards the trade agreements themselves and so I'm writing this as a comment only.

Comment: From Spain, a key import was wolfram and other metals; the UK organized a campaign in order to buy as much wolfram as was available to deny it to Germany (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spain_during_World_War_II#Resources_and_trade)

Comment: Quite _lovely_ comments, though, I'm waiting for a complete answer. ;)

Comment: Don't worry. Our members will not wait for an invitation to comment.

Comment: Yep! It has been _quite_ evident on this post.

Comment: Before the US entered the war they obviously imported the syrup used to make Coca-Cola.

Comment: Just want to say thank you to all of those who have contributed to this question thread and below! My research paper is turning out to be quite phenomenal, thanks to the extensive knowledge of you all! :)

Comment: I'd recommend reading ["The Wages of Destruction:The Making and Breaking of the Nazi Economy"](https://www.amazon.com/Wages-Destruction-Making-Breaking-Economy/dp/0143113208) by Adam Tooze.  It's excellent, and covers German exports/imports in great detail.

Comment: Perfect recommendation! I actually borrowed that book from my library about 2 months ago, and it was very crucial to my research assignment.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Germany lacked raw resources, mostly oil, rubber, manganese, nickel, iron, chrome &c, as well as food.

This is what they tried to get from wherever they could.

I believe the most important Germany's trade partner in the first third of the war (1939-1941) was the USSR. 
Everyone knows about the [Molotov-Ribbentrop Pact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molotov-Ribbentrop_Pact) and its secret protocols, but the trade agreements ([1939](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German-Soviet_Credit_Agreement_(1939)) and [1940](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German-Soviet_Commercial_Agreement_(1940))) were no less important for [British blockade failure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German%E2%80%93Soviet_Commercial_Agreement_(1940)#British_blockade_failure).

USSR supplied petroleum, manganese, copper, nickel, chrome, platinum, lumber and grain &c (see numbers and references in the wikipedia links above).

Other important trade partners were Sweden (iron), Rumania (oil) &c.

They also "imported" industrial products from occupied France (trucks) and Czechoslovakia (tanks) - see also my answer to [Did France & Italy continue to develop and manufacture sophisticated military hardware once under German control?](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/10296/1979)

A good source is ["*Inside the 3rd Reich*" by Speer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inside_the_Third_Reich).

You might find http://ww2-weapons.com/military-expenditures-strategic-raw-materials-oil-production/ useful too.

See also [Was one of the main reasons Hitler attacked the Soviet Union due to oil?](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/37878/1979).

Answer (score 7):

Germany largely lacked industrial metals such as iron, tungsten, and chrome. They traded for iron with [Sweden,](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/16753/why-did-hitler-not-invade-sweden) tungsten with [Spain,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spain_during_World_War_II#Resources_and_trade) and chrome with [Turkey](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/16806/why-didnt-germany-attack-turkey-during-ww2).

All of these were neutral countries, and their importance in supplying key raw materials was a major reason why Germany allowed them to stay neutral. If Germany had occupied them, and then lost them to a counterinvasion by e.g. the Soviet Union or the western allies, it would have lost the war faster than it actually did.

Comment: Great content, but where did you find this information? Just a small issue, no worries.

Comment: @BirlantisEscheatvc: Added links to SE articles on Sweden and Turkey. A reference to Spain and tungsten (wolfram) was in one of the comments.

Comment: Oh—didn't notice. Thank you, @TomAu!

Comment: @TomAu Just a reminder that comments may be deleted, and maybe you should put the link in your answer. Or even better, some excerpts.

Answer (score -2):

Sweden, Denmark, Norway, Switzerland, Austria and Italy ware dependent on German and Polish coal. So were The Netherlands, Belgium and Luxembourg.

How dependent France was on German coal i'm unsure about.

Remove Belgium from my list, how large part of the amount of coal which they used and which was Belgian i'm unsure about but they had until the 50s sizable reserves of coal themselves.

Comment: Why did i get a down-vote on this ???? At least Scandinavia was dependent on german or polish coal.

Comment: I dunno. Perhaps because you state The Netherlands, Belgium and Luxembourg relied on German coal?